# SharePoint folder permission programatically

Tags: document-library, permissions

In SharePoint 2013, I have a document library with a folder structure. If a user is created using the form based authentication then automatically their respective folder is created in the document library using a program.

Now my requirement is, the created folder will be edited/viewed by the user who has been added to the system and other user should not able to view or edit that folder.

How to do this using program?

Answer (score 0):

please have a look in this answere for how to do it programmatically:
[Problem Setting Item Level Permissions Dynamically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41565/problem-setting-item-level-permissions-dynamically)

or this article:
https://akifkamalsyed.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/how-to-progammatically-set-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/

The following code which come form the link above is posted if the link becomes unavailable:

```
public void ItemLevelPermissions(SPWeb web, SPListItem item, string userName)
 {
    try
     {
        if(!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments){
            item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
            SPPrincipalInfo user = SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(web, userName, SPPrincipalType.All, SPPrincipalSource.All, null, false);
            SPRoleDefinition RoleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
            SPPrincipal member = null;

            if(user.IsSharePointGroup)
                { member = web.Groups.GetByID(user.PrincipalId); }
            else
                { member = web.AllUsers.GetByID(user.PrincipalId); }

            if ((item.GetUserEffectivePermissions(userName) & SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems) == 0)
            {
                SPRoleAssignment RoleAssignment = newSPRoleAssignment(member);
                RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(RoleDefinition);
                item.RoleAssignments.Add(RoleAssignment);
            }

            item.SystemUpdate();
        }
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
        ExceptionHandler.LogException(ex);
     }

}
```

Comment: Thank you sebastian.i will use this and tell you the result.